# How to add an annotation outside of a node in Graphviz' dot?

Tags: eclipse, graphviz, dot, zest

I am very new to Dot and trying to visualize a callgraph with Dot and Zest in Eclipse. And I would like to annotate nodes with kind of annotation (OK and Failed on the pic.).

[image: Annotated graph I want to get]

Is there any common way to do this for Dot or Zest?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**`xlabel`**

Have a look at `xlabel` (external label).

main.dot

```
graph {
    node [shape=square];
    1 [xlabel="a"]
    2 [xlabel="b"]
    1 -- 2;
}
```

Convert:

```
dot -Tpng main.dot > main.png
```

Output:

[image]

Not sure however how easily you can control exact label placement with this method: even overlaps can happen by default. See:

- [Graphviz graph positioning xlabels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30689533/graphviz-graph-positioning-xlabels)
- [xlabels for nodes overlap with edges in dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20910932/xlabels-for-nodes-overlap-with-edges-in-dot)

**`shape=record`**

I just tend to prefer the `shape=record` approach mentioned by https://stackoverflow.com/a/23031506/895245 or their generalization, HTML-like labels, as it makes it clearer what label belongs to each node:

```
graph {
    rankdir=LR
    node [shape=record];
    1 [label="1|a"]
    2 [label="2|b"]
    1 -- 2;
}
```

Output:

[image]

TODO can you avoid typing `1` and `2` twice?

Tested on Ubuntu 16.10, graphviz 2.38.

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported by the Zest rendering, but on the DOT level you could use record-based nodes:

```
rankdir=LR;
node [shape=record];
m1[label="void m1()|OK"];
m1[label="void m2()|Failed"];
```

For details see http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#record