# Graphviz graph positioning xlabels

Tags: graphviz

I have tried using xlp and also followed this graphviz thread (http://www.graphviz.org/content/how-use-xlp-attribute-positioning-external-labels-xlabel), but neither have actually worked.

This is my dot code:

```
digraph {
    forcelabels=true;
    rankdir=LR;
    graph[ranksep=1,nodesep=.5];
    node[shape=box];
    "start" [xlabel="start",xlp="0,0",shape=doublecircle,label=" "];
    "requested"->"fault";
    "requested"->"progress";
    "start"->"requested";
    "progress"->"fault";
    "progress"->"progress";
    "progress"->"complete";
    "fault" [xlabel="fault",shape=doublecircle,label=" "];
    "complete" [xlabel="complete",shape=doublecircle,label=" "];
}
```

And this is what it looks like:
[image]

Ideally start,fault, and complete would just be directly under the nodes, but  I can't seem to postion the xlabels correctly.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, I also want to position labels under the nodes but there seems to be no tutorial or anything on how to do it.

Comment: I tried xlabels, but their positioning seems to be broken

Comment: I've been looking at the data generated by dot - and changing the xlp information doesn't seem to do anything  cf. http://www.graphviz.org/content/how-use-xlp-attribute-positioning-external-labels-xlabel
Likewise with changing the actual pos values.

Comment: I realise this comment is late to the party (and things may have changed) but in [the docs](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html) it states in the table of attributes: `xlp 
  NE   point   write only`. Then above that table it states: "_write only_ indicates that the attribute is used for output, and is not used or read by any of the layout programs" which explains why setting it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you use `neato` with the `-n2` flag, you should be able to set the position of `xlabel`. You would need to specify the position of every node, though.

So if you had a file called `lb.gv` with the following contents:

```
digraph{
    forcelabels=true;
    rankdir=LR;
    graph[ranksep=1,nodesep=.5,margin=0.3,bgcolor=Transparent];

    node[shape=box];
    start [pos="0,0", xlp="23,54", xlabel=start, shape=doublecircle, label= " "];
    requested [pos="100,0"];
    progress [pos="250,-66"];
    fault [pos="400,70", xlp="424,124", xlabel=fault, shape=doublecircle,label= " "];
    complete [pos="400,-66", xlp="424,-10", xlabel=complete, shape=doublecircle,label= " "];
    requested->fault;
    requested->progress;
    start->requested;
    progress->fault;
    progress:w->progress:_;
    progress->complete;
}
```

You could run `neato -n2 -Tpng lb.gv > test.png`

That's what I got:

[image: graphviz]

Comment: Note: this *forces* you to place everything explicitly, which is a pain, and half defeats the purpose of graphviz.

Comment: @CiroSantilli烏坎事件2016六四事件法轮功 That's a bummer indeed. That's why there is an open feature request ticket for it: http://www.graphviz.org/mantisbt/view.php?id=2410

Comment: I face the same problem, it seems that the feature to avoid to place everything explicitly is still not available ?

Comment: @IvanChaer the feature request is now https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/issues/299 and https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/issues/68

Answer (score 3):

- Use newlines in **label** string to drop text below node
- set **fixedsize=true** to keep node size to default
- add **cluster** to keep lowest labels from being truncated

```
digraph {
    rankdir=LR;
    graph[ranksep=1,nodesep=.5];
    //  add a cluster to provide "margin" for labels below nodes
    subgraph cluster_space {
      graph [peripheries=0]
      node[shape=box];
      // dot ignores xlp
      // add newlines to shift label down
      // fixedsize=true to keep node sized correctly
      "start" [label="\n\n\n\nstart" shape=doublecircle fixedsize=true ];
      "requested"
      "progress"
      "complete" [label="\n\n\n\ncomplete" shape=doublecircle fixedsize=true]
      "fault" [label="\n\n\n\nfault" shape=doublecircle fixedsize=true]

      "requested"->"fault";
      "requested"->"progress";
      "start"->"requested";
      "progress"->"fault";
      "progress"->"progress";
      "progress"->"complete";
    }
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you are asking, but you could try something like:

```
digraph nodes_as_labels {
    rankdir=LR;
    graph[ranksep=1,nodesep=.5];
    node[shape=box];

    "start" [xlp="0,0",shape=doublecircle,label=" "];
    "fault" [shape=doublecircle,label=" "];
    "complete" [shape=doublecircle,label=" "];
    "startlabel" [label="start",penwidth="0"];
    "faultlabel" [label="fault",penwidth="0"];
    "completelabel" [label="complete",penwidth="0"];

    "startlabel" -> "start"[style="invis"];
    "requested"->"fault";
    "requested"->"progress";
    "start"->"requested";
    "progress"->"fault";
    "progress"->"progress";
    "progress"->"complete";
    "fault" -> "faultlabel"[style="invis"];
    "complete" -> "completelabel"[style="invis"];
}
```

This results in:

[image: gv converted to png]

This approach is more relevant when you are using the neato or fdp layout engine, because then you can use the [len](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/len/) attribute to set the distance between the nodes that act as label and the nodes you are labeling.  This way you can prevent the labels from overlapping edges.  Unfortunately, the `len` attribute does not work for the dot layout engine that the example is using, which is why the labels in the result are far away from the nodes they are labeling.